# How can i use local storage access token in server side to fetch data?

Tags: next.js

I was using nextjs and .net as backend. I want to use client side component and server side data fetching features. But it needs to be authenticated. As the authentication uses local storage to saved the access_token. Now the problem here is for data fetching we need accesstoken, which is stored in the local storage which is only accessed by client side. How can i solved this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not access local storage at SSR .
so you can use cookies

```html
const encodedToken = request.cookies.get("token");

//for storing 

 const tokenString = JSON.stringify(data);
        const encodedToken = btoa(tokenString);
        setCookie(null, "token", encodedToken, {
          maxAge: 30 * 24 * 60 * 60,
          path: "/",
        });
```